# Trying to grab window height - set pixels and style.height to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, settimeout

I am trying, after a set time, grab the height of the window, then set the height of an existing DIV to the current height minus the menu bar's on top (148px). I am successfully getting the height however the DIV style.height is not setting to the new calculated height. The height of the DIV before the event is triggered is 170px.

JS

```
setTimeout(function() {
    var currentHeight = $(window).height() - 148;
    console.log('before ' + currentHeight);
    fullContractorSection.style.height = "'"+currentHeight+"px'";
    var full = $(fullContractorSection).height();
    console.log('after ' + full);
}, 100);
```

Console

```
before 568
after 170
```

Comment: Have you selected fullContractorSection before setting its height?

Comment: @SatishKumar aw yes, that's what was missing. Thank you for the hint! It works now after: $(fullContractorSection).height(currentHeight);